# issue on how to delete random number from magento

Tags: magento, url, url-rewriting, categories

one of category keeps making random url at the end of key url like:

http://www.m2motorsportinc.com/custom-wheels/wheels-brand/rohana-wheels-22.html

Weird thing is only this category makes the random number.

Is there any wayto delete the random number?

Thankyou

Answer (score 0):

The issue is caused by duplicate url paths `../wheels-brand/rohana-wheels.html` being saved in the db. The system keeps the old path reserved in the table `core_url_rewrite`

- BACKUP DB
- Truncate `core_url_rewrite` table OR
- Query `core_url_rewrite` and delete rows with `custom-wheels/wheels-brand/rohana-wheels.html` in the request_path

Go to Catalog > Manage Categories > Select 'Rohana Wheels' Category

- Clear URL Key, re-enter `rohana-wheels` and resave
- Go to System > Index Management, rebuild `Catalog URL Rewrites`
- Flush Cache
- Correct sitemap path at `/sitemap.xml`
- Submit updated sitemap to Google, et al.

If it is acceptable you can also change the category paths site wide, you can remove the category suffix `.html` from the path `../wheels-brand/rohana-wheels` by entering a `/` in the textfield `Admin > System > Configuration > Catalog > Search Engine Optimizations > Category URL Suffix` then flush cache and reload.